# Do I have to implement commutativity for comparison operators manually?

Tags: c++, c++11, comparison, operator-overloading

With *n* different classes, which should all be comparable with `operator==` and `operator!=`, it would be necessary to implement *(n ^ 2 - n) * 2* operators manually. (At least I think that's the term)

That would be 12 for three classes, 24 for four. I know that I can implement a lot of them in terms of other operators like so:

```
operator==(A,B); //implemented elsewhere

operator==(B,A){ return A == B; }

operator!=(A,B){ return !(A == B); }
```

but it still seems very tedious, especially because `A == B` will always yield the same result as `B == A` and there seems to be no reason whatsoever to implement two version of them.

*Is there a way around this? Do I really have to implement `A == B` and `B == A` manually?*

Comment: not that I know of. but this sounds like you need to structure your class hierarchy in such a way that the types can be subsumed by a common base class so that you only need to implement `operator=(Base,Base)`

Comment: Sounds like bad design, but sounds also interesting to hear what the community has to say on the subject, so +1.

Comment: If you are comparing objects of different types, you are doing something either very very wrong or very very clever (which is indistinguishable from very very wrong in the long run).

Comment: @Pavel I wanted to say that wouldn't make any sense in my usecase, but I guess private inheritance would work.

Comment: @n.m. I am implementing wrappers for smart pointers that have different behaviour, but after all should all be comparable to one another. In the end, I'm comparing pointers that point (of course) to the same type.

Comment: You might be able to write a template and then use `enable_if` to restrict it just to objects of your type.

Comment: @templatetypedef fitting username, I must say. I already thought about some template magic with a templated comparison operator (though I'm not sure if that is even allowed by the standard)

Comment: Oh, a family of closely related types. When the minor differences are factored out, it's actually a single type. Looks legit. You probably can define a single *template* comparison operator that accepts any type of the family at either position.

Comment: Is it OK if the `operator==` all delegate to a `compare(A,B)` function that you write, instead of `operator==`?  Because otherwise any template solution is going to be ambiguous or infinitely recursive and couldn't actually call the one you manually wrote.

Comment: @MooingDuck I do that with as few as possbile member `operator==`. It would of course be a good idea to rename that to `equals` or something similar to prevent accidental recursions.

Comment: @iFreilicht: Depending on what I'm doing, I sometimes have a `int T::compare(const T&) const` function, that mimics `strcmp`, and then it's trivial to write all of the 6+ comparison functions in terms of that one.  Depends on the type though

Comment: @MooingDuck It's trivial for me either way, but I have multiple types that can be compared to one another, so I don't really want to go through it, as trivial as it may be. Also, my classes are templates so the header file becomes quite cluttered by 12 comparison operators...

Answer (score 8):

Use [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/libs/utility/operators.htm), then you only need to implement one, and boost will define the rest of the boilerplate for you.

```
struct A
{};

struct B : private boost::equality_comparable<B, A>
{
};

bool operator==(B const&, A const&) {return true;}
```

This allows instances of `A` and `B` to be compared for equality/inequality in any order.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7715381a4ca151e2)

*Note:* `private` inheritance works here because of the [Barton–Nackman trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton%E2%80%93Nackman_trick).

Comment: What does the last line mean? surely, `A == B` shouldn't return `true` all the time, right?

Comment: @iFreilicht No, most likely not. It's just a sample implementation :). The real implementation would probably compare data members of `A` and `B` to determine equality.

Comment: Careful if you generalize this, as you mixed up the operands! If you are using the two-argument form with `<T,U>`, you should derive from `T`, not from `U`. See the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/operators.htm#two_arg) of Boost.Operators. For the comparison operators this is actually allowed, but other readers might not be aware of it so it would IMHO be better to be consistent here.

Comment: @DanielFrey Thank you for the heads up! I've never used the 2 argument forms myself, only seen them in the documentation. So I wasn't aware of this caveat.

Comment: Something I just noticed: does this work for three or more types?

Comment: @iFreilicht Yep, [it does](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/793a9cea89720cb5).

Comment: @iFreilicht While what Praetorian says is correct, there is one more thing to note: If you happen to write code on Windows, consider using [base-class chaining](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/operators.htm#chaining) to keep the size of the classes small, i.e., use `struct C : private boost::equality_comparable<C, A, boost::equality_comparable<C, B>> {};`. Ugly syntax, but sadly necessary due to a messed up ABI on Windows. If you are on Linux, ... you can safely ignore this :)

Comment: @DanielFrey I am in fact developing on Windows so this is good to know. From what the link says, it looks like base-class chaining is the more portable choice in general, right? PS: I have an irrational fear of multiple inheritance, I want to avoid it as much as `export`.

Comment: @iFreilicht Both are portable, but I personally prefer multiple inheritance over base-class chaining because it's the more logical interface. I don't like the fact that implementation and optimization details are reflected on the API, but for Windows there is no real alternative. And if you want to be portable to several systems including Windows, then just go for base-class chaining. I'd probably add a comment somewhere to make sure the guy inheriting my code doesn't break it. For the PS: Fear is lack of knowledge. Just know when and why multiple inheritance causes problems like the above :)

Comment: @DanielFrey So if you don't use base class chaining, is the only penalty you pay with MSVC increased class size, or is the behavior incorrect too? Also, feel free to edit my answer (or write your own, of course) with any details you feel are important.

Comment: The behavior will always be correct whether you use base-class chaining or not. It is just the per-instance size that might be increased unnecessarily.

Answer (score 4):

In the comments the problem is further explained by stating that all of the types are really different forms of smart pointers with some underlying type. Now this simplifies quite a lot the problem.

You can implement a generic template for the operation:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
bool operator==(T const & lhs, U const & rhs) {
   return std::addressof(*lhs) == std::addressof(*rhs);
}
```

Now this is a bad catch all (or rather catch too many) implementation. But you can narrow down the scope of the operator by providing a trait `is_smart_ptr` that detects whether `Ptr1` and `Ptr2` are one of your smart pointers, and then use SFINAE to filter out:

```
template <typename T, typename U,
          typename _ = typename std::enable_if<is_pointer_type<T>::value 
                                            && is_pointer_type<U>::value>::type >
bool operator==(T const & lhs, U const & rhs) {
   return std::addressof(*lhs) == std::addressof(*rhs);
}
```

The type trait itself can be just a list of specializations of a template:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_pointer_type : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_pointer_type<T*> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_pointer_type<MySmartPointer<T>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_pointer_type<AnotherPointer<T>> : std::true_type {};
```

It probably makes sense not to list all of the types that match the concept of pointer, but rather test for the concept, like:

```
template <typename T, typename U,
          typename _ = decltype(*declval<T>())>
bool operator==(T const & lhs, U const & rhs) {
   return std::addressof(*lhs) == std::addressof(*rhs);
}
```

Where the concept being tested is that it has `operator*` exists. You could extend the SFINAE check to verify that the stored pointer types are comparable (i.e. that `std::addressof(*lhs)` and `std::addressof(*rhs)` has a valid equality:

```
template <typename T, typename U,
          typename _ = decltype(*declval<T>())>
auto operator==(T const & lhs, U const & rhs) 
                -> decltype(std::addressof(*lhs) == std::addressof(*rhs))
{
   return std::addressof(*lhs) == std::addressof(*rhs);
}
```

And this is probably as far as you can really get: You can compare anything that looks like a pointer to two possibly unrelated objects, if raw pointers to those types are comparable. You might need to single out the case where *both* arguments are raw pointers to avoid this entering out into a recursive requirement...

Comment: Very cool solution, though I'm not quite sure if I really understand it. What do the `template <typename>` template arguments do? How does the `typename _` pervent the template from being instantiated with non-pointer types? Sorry for asking, I don't have much experience with templates, they still seem very obscure to me at times.

Comment: @iFreilicht A template parameter of the form `template <typename> Name` is called a "template *template-parameter*". Its argument must be a *class template*. That is, `Ptr1` is a class template with one template type parameter; `Ptr1<T>` then is a specialization of that template. -- `typename _` here, `_` is just a weird name. The magic is the `enable_if`, which is used to apply a technique called "SFINAE" (Substitution Failure in the immediate context Is Not An Error).

Comment: @iFreilicht: Sorry, that is really a left over from a previous attempt that I did not quite cleanup. dyp correctly explained it, but it does not make sense as this places a stricter than needed constrain on your smart pointers: a single template argument. I am removing it from the answer as of now.

Answer (score 3):

not necesarily:

```
template<class A, class B>
bool operator==(const A& a, const B& b)
{ return b==a; }
```

works for whatever A and B there is a B==A implementation (otherwise will recourse infinitely)

You can also use CRTP if you don't want the templetized == to work for everything:

```
template<class Derived>
class comparable {};

class A: public comparable<A>
{ ... };

class B: public comparable<B>
{ ... };

bool operator==(const A& a, const B& b) 
{ /* direct */ }

// this define all reverses
template<class T, class U>
bool operator==(const comparable<T>& sa, const comparable<U>& sb)
{ return static_cast<const U&>(sb) == static_cast<const T&>(sa); }

//this defines inequality
template<class T, class U>
bool operator!=(const comparable<T>& sa, const comparable<U>& sb)
{ return !(static_cast<const T&>(sa) == static_cast<const U&>(sb)); }
```

---

Using return type SFINAE yo ucan even do something like

```
template<class A, class B>
auto operator==(const A& a, const B& b) -> decltype(b==a) 
{ return b==a; }

template<class A, class B>
auto operator!=(const A& a, const B& b) -> decltype(!(a==b))
{ return !(a==b); }
```

Comment: You can avoid public inheritance by using SFINAE + `is_base_of`. Alternatively: a custom trait (no inheritance required).

Comment: absolutely, but can be harder to explain to someone that seems even not so accustomed with templates ... Feel free to post yourself that solution, I'll vote for it!

Comment: I think your return type SFINAE is ambiguous and/or infinitely recursive.  (Actually, so is your primary example)  I think it would be better to make sets of `compare(A,B)` functions that the `operator==` can delegate too.

Comment: I stand corrected for your primary example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18c40c4a9c48b785, though the SFINAE acts as I supposed: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d032fe6f384d22be

Comment: um, what exactly does that `-> decltype(b==a)` syntax do or what is it called?

Comment: @iFreilicht `decltype` stands for *declared type of*, but it also yields *the type of an expression* if not directly applied to the name of a variable. `decltype(42)` is `int` etc., `decltype(b==a)` is the type of the expression `b==a`, that is, whatever the comparison operator returns.

Comment: @dyp what about the strange `->`? I've only ever seen it like that in lambda expressions, but why would you specify the return type like that? I would also appreciate a link where I could read up on this, you don't have to explain it to me, necessarily.

Comment: @iFreilicht That's a *trailing-return-type*. Both are C++11 features. I think with the names *decltype* and *trailing return type*, you should be equipped to perform a google search.

Comment: @iFreilicht: If a regular function has a return type of `auto`, then it can use the `-> TYPE` trailing return specifier that lambdas do.  They're the same thing.  Trailing returns + decltype work MAGIC!

Answer (score 2):

The goal here is to deal with large n reasonably efficiently.

We create an order, and forward all comparison operators to `comp` after reordering them to obey that order.

To do this, I start with some metaprogramming boilerplate:

```
template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};
template<class T,class types>struct index_of{};
template<class T,class...Ts>struct index_of<T,types<T,Ts...>>:
  std::integral_constant<unsigned,0>
{};
template<class T,class U,class...Us>struct index_of<T,types<U,Us...>>:
  std::integral_constant<unsigned,1+index_of<T,types<Us...>>::value>
{};
```

which lets us talk about ordered lists of types.  Next we use this to impose an order on these types:

```
template<class T, class U,class types>
struct before:
  std::integral_constant<bool, (index_of<T,types>::value<index_of<U,types>::value)>
{};
```

Now we make some toy types and a list:

```
struct A{}; struct B{}; struct C{};
typedef types<A,B,C> supp;

int comp(A,B);
int comp(A,C);
int comp(B,C);
int comp(A,A);
int comp(B,B);
int comp(C,C);

template<class T,class U>
std::enable_if_t<before<T,U,supp>::value, bool>
operator==(T const& t, U const& u) {
  return comp(t,u)==0;
}
template<class T,class U>
std::enable_if_t<!before<T,U, supp>::value, bool>
operator==(T const& t, U const& u) {
  return comp(u,t)==0;
}
template<class T,class U>
std::enable_if_t<before<T,U,supp>::value, bool>
operator<(T const& t, U const& u) {
  return comp(t,u)<0;
}
template<class T,class U>
std::enable_if_t<!before<T,U, supp>::value, bool>
operator<(T const& t, U const& u) {
  return comp(u,t)>0;
}
```

etc.

The basic idea is that `supp` lists the types you want to support, and their prefered order.

Boilerplate operators then forward everything to `comp`.

You need to implement n*(n-1)/2 `comp`s to handles each pair, but only in one order.

Now for the bad news: probably you want to lift each type to some common type and compare there, rather than het lost in the combinatorial morass.

Suppose you can define a type `Q` which can store the imformation required to sort any of them.

Then write convert-to-`Q` code from each type, and implement comparison on `Q`.  This reduces the code written to O(a+b), where `a` is the number of types and `b` the number of operators supported.

As an example, smart pointers can be pointer-ordered between each other this way.